# Дублирование знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Допускается ли постановка в предложении одного пунктуационного знака (например, тире или двоеточия) несколько раз, если для постановки каждого из них есть свое основание?

Answer (score 6):

Конечно, допускается. Вполне возможно тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, а потом между частями сложного предложения. Но также допускается и замена одного знака на другой для лучшего зрительного восприятия предложения. Все зависит от конкретного случая. Приводите примеры.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Возможно, это идиотский вопрос, но как определить, когда постановка двух выделительных тире допустима, а когда эти знаки могут быть приняты за двойное тире?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что следует избегать постановки двух  двоеточий или двух функционально разных тире в одном предложении. В этом случае знаки препинания  в недостаточной мере проясняют грамматику предложения (например, два разных тире можно принять за обособленный речевой отрезок), интонация предложения также непонятна. Даже чисто графически такое предложение плохо смотрится. Запятых это также касается - например, ряд однородных членов, разделенный запятыми, лучше обособить с помощью тире, а не запятых.

Comment: Избегание постановки двух тире, выполняющих разделительную функцию, оправдано, т. к. их можно принять за парный выделительный знак. Но чем мотивировано избегание постановки двух и более двоеточий? Конечно, Вы уже привели немало аргументов против употребления нескольких функционально разных знаков в одном предложении, но я хочу выяснить, существует ли запрет на использование двух двоеточий в предложении или мысль о невозможности такой пунктуационной схемы - предрассудок.

Comment: Запрет – это интересно сказано.  Думаю, что все авторы орфографических учебников действуют из следующего принципа: разрешено всё, что не запрещено правилами 1956 года.  Запрета нет, но, может быть, кто-нибудь уже высказывался по этой теме. В то же время практически два двоеточия подряд обычно не применяются.

Comment: Возьмем, к примеру,  следующее предложение: А к нам идёт угрюмая зима: засохла степь, лес  глохнет и желтеет (И.Бунин). Попробуем его немного переделать: Я думал: к нам идёт угрюмая зима: засохла степь, лес  глохнет и желтеет. Графически два двоеточия «не смотрятся», и в устной речи мы должны сделать две предупредительные паузы, что не очень удобно. Поэтому лучше заменить  одно двоеточие: Я думал: к нам идёт угрюмая зима – засохла степь, лес  глохнет и желтеет.